# check if table cell is empty using php

Tags: php, mysql

can I check table cell is empty or not by using PHP? 
I am doing a report using for loop, when the section didn't filled up it will not display the table so it made the table looks weird.[image: so if they didn't filled one of the section, it will display in this way.]

```
    echo"<table width='100%' border='3' class='table table-striped' style='font-size:12px;'>";

    for($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++){
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $totalsum=0;

    $query5 = "SELECT * FROM outlet_type_location WHERE id = '$row[outlet_type_location_id]'";
    $result5 = $db->query($query5);
    $row5 = $result5->fetch_array();

    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<th width='15%'>".$row5['location']."</th>";

    $query2 = "SELECT section_mark FROM audit_section_section_mark WHERE audit_section_no = '$row[audit_no]'";
    $result2 = $db->query($query2);
    $num_results2 = $result2->num_rows; 

    for($j=0;$j<$num_results2;$j++){
    $row2 = $result2->fetch_array();

    $ss_mark = $row2['section_mark'];

    echo"<td width='10%' align='center' id='my_cell'>$ss_mark</td>";
    }

    //listing total result
    echo"<td width='10%' align='center'>";
    if($totalsum < 70){
        echo"<font color='red'><b>$totalsum/100</b></font>"; 
    }else if($totalsum >= 80){
        echo"<font color='#00CC33'><b>$totalsum/100</b></font>"; 
    }
    else{
        echo"<font><b>$totalsum/100</b></font>";    
    }
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}

echo"</table>";
```

[image]

Comment: PHP is server side scripting, to check on client side you can use javascript/JQuery

Comment: Looking at your code, you are outputting the content of your table during an executing of a query, making creation of cells query-dependent, so if your query result only has two rows, like in your example, you tend to have missing cells.

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm can you give me some hints to make it nicely?

Comment: Use `$num_results` as your basis for checking since I think this is your baseline. I was trying to formulate an answer but I can't quite understand your code since you are using `for` instead in the more common `while fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm you may formulate your answer. I will try to digest it :)

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm I already update my code bro :)

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm bro, the latest picture all the table display nicely. but the mark is only display on first three

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm bro, updated image :)

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm Hi bro, can I have your email or facebook? Similar problem need to seek for you advice.

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm add me jxlim_22@hotmail.com :))

Comment: @Andrew, just ask another question, it may increase your reputation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (tested):

```
    $query2 = "SELECT section_mark FROM audit_section_section_mark WHERE audit_section_no = '$row[audit_no]'";
    $result2 = $db->query($query2);
    $num_results2 = $result2->num_rows; 

if($num_results2 != 0){
        for($j=0;$j<$num_results1;$j++){
            $row2 = $result2->fetch_array();
                if(isset($row2['section_mark'])){
                 echo "<td width='10%' align='center' id='my_cell'>" . $row2['section_mark']. "</td>";
                    }else{
                echo "<td width='10%' align='center' id='my_cell'>-</td>";
            }
        }
}
else{
    for($j=0;$j<$num_results1;$j++){
        echo"<td width='10%' align='center' id='my_cell'></td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the second `$row2['section_mark'][$j]`?

Comment: yes bro; after that output become single digit. but the mark should be like what I upload in my question :(

Comment: I think is didnt loop the answer :(

Comment: bro I found solution :) thanks dude
let me edit your post and upvote you yaaa <3